# TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror

Full error:
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::KeyboardEvent@4ff2301 to flash.events.MouseEvent.

I followed a really simple tutorial for a simple quiz using ActionScript 3. However once complete I receive the above error. The tutorial is quite old so was just hoping if someone here could just check it and see if I have made an obvious mistake.

```
    Enter_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go);

var quizModel:Array = [{q:"2+2", a:"4"}, {q:"What colour is a banana = ?", a:"Yellow"}];
var user_ans:Array = new Array();
var newQuizModel:Array = shuffleArray(quizModel);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, go);


function showQuiz(index:int):void
{
    question_txt.text = newQuizModel[index]["q"];
}


var index:int = 0;
question_txt.text = newQuizModel[index]["q"];
var userAnswer:String = "";
function go(e:MouseEvent)
{


    userAnswer = answers_txt.text;

    if (userAnswer == newQuizModel[index]["a"])
    {
        rightwrong_txt.text = "Your answer is correct!";
    }
    else
    {
        rightwrong_txt.text = "Your answer is wrong";
        return;
    }

    index++;
    index%= quizModel.length;
    showQuiz(index);
}

function shuffleArray(arr:Array):Array
{
    var l:Number = arr.length - 1;

    for (var it:uint = 0; it<l; it++)
    {
        var r:int = Math.round(Math.random() * l);  /// l is an L
        var tmp:Object = arr[it];
        arr[it] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
}


showQuiz(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `go(e:MouseEvent)` with `go(e:Event)`.

You registered one event handler to MouseEvent and KeyboardEvent. When `MouseEvent.CLICK` will be fired, function `go` will be called. An instance of `MouseEvent` will be passed inside function `go`. There is no error. But when `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` will be fired, instance of KeyboardEvent will be passed inside `go` function. And error happens. Sorry for my English. Do you understand?

Comment: Ok I fixed all the errors. Thanks for your advice. I needed to remove keyboard.Key_Down as I was not using it anyway.